# Javascript/CSS: Fade string of text as it gets longer

Tags: javascript, css

I have searched for an answer to this and it may exist somewhere but I am not sure how to explain it, I keep finding methods to fade text on/off load which is not how I am trying to do this. I am trying to fade some text on the same line, and I will attach a simulated screenshot I made in Photoshop :

[image: font fade]

In the current font family and size I have set, I would like it to start to fade around 20 chars or so into the text. Ideally, if I can do something like...

```
<span class="fadeout">
```

or something of the like, it would be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your background color is known (ie black, as in the image above), then you could use a Pseudo CSS selector like so to simulate the effect:

```css
.fadeout {
  position:relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.fadeout:after {
  content:'';
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg ,transparent,black);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<span class="fadeout">This is a test test long text for example</span>
```

Comment: I like your solution, of which I've also done many times. But you may want to consider putting `pointer-events` in your CSS for click through to make it more natural.

Comment: great suggestion - thanks for that. I've just made the adjustment to my answer

Answer (score 5):

What you want effectively is gradient text (webkit only!):

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #000);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
body {
  background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Test text that is long</h1>
```

This will begin the fade at the start of the text. If you want to start after a specific point, then you have no choice but to wrap the faded part of the text in a `span`:

```css
span.fade {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #000);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
  
h1 {
  color:white
}
  
body {
  background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Test text that is long <span class="fade">but only begins to fade here</span></h1>
```

Comment: _“If you want to start after a specific point, then you have no choice but to wrap the faded part of the text in a span”_ - you could also just add another color stop to your gradient, something like `-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 5em, #000)` - the `5em` are a bit of a “magic number” here of course, but it might make even more sense than going by a specific number of characters in the text I think.

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is that it completely disregards Internet Explorer. IE11 is still quite commonly used, and there is no support for `text-fill-color`. Always best to check for support of CSS properties if cross-browser support is an important part of a project: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-fill-color

Comment: @stybl unfortunate these cool properties cannot be standardized across browsers. Standardization would make our lives much easier! Your solution is very elegant otherwise.